# SQLite группировки и итоги по всем группировкам

Tags: android, sqlite

Мне нужна небольшая консультация, можно без кода.

У меня есть простая БД с полями: вид движения (ходьба, бег и т.д.), дата (timestamp) и расстояние.

Я хочу сделать запрос с несколькими группировками, например: вид движения, месяц, неделя, день и вычислить сумму расстояний. Причем итоги мне нужны по всем группировкам: по виду движения, за месяц, за неделю, за день. (кстати группировку по неделям с первым днем "Понедельник" я сделал, несмотря на кучу ошибок в функции `STRFTIME` в исполнении Андроид 12).

Когда я делаю один запрос я вижу итоги только по дням. Я правильно понял, что нужно делать подзапросы для каждой группировки? Или есть какое-то ключевое слово позволяющее включать строки с итогами?

Comment: Запрос может использовать результаты других запросов, типа `SELECT (SELECT <expression1>) + (SELECT <expression2>) as 'resultColumnName'`

Comment: @Yura Ivanov По моему вопрос предельно ясный. Мне не нужна помощь в составлении конкретного запроса. Пример примитивный и я ожидал рекомендаций по наиболее лучшему или простому варианту реализации.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov От вас конкретно ничего не нужно. Ваши предположения и ощущения оставьте при себе.